# Orientation of a known object in an image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have a picture with a known, simple object, e.g. chessboard. The camera can have different angles, distances etc.

What is the "standard" object detection algorithm to detect the object's position, angle and tilt? From those three, position is probably the simplest one, later rotation and the tilt..

I am aware that it is not an easy task, and there might be plenty of algorithms that bite this problem, yet for an object known beforehand there might be some commonly used solution (like [eigenfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) for face recognition)

Comment: probably better on dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) has an implementation for this called [findChessboardCorners](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findchessboard#bool%20findChessboardCorners%28InputArray%20image,%20Size%20patternSize,%20OutputArray%20corners,%20int%20flags%29). [Here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp) is the code they use to detect it. They also have a whole slew of functions for camera calibration and determining the extrinsic parameters. [Here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp) is one of their samples for calibrating a camera.

Finally, [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=chessboard%20detection&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,1&as_sdtp=on) has many papers available on this topic.

Comment: I had no idea that there is whole "chessboard" research topic, it was just an example :) thanks!